# How to achieve this Desaturated/Flat yet Vibrant with Tanned skin tones in LR/PS?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, effect

I LOVE the look and style of this photographer and I'm looking to see how she gets this look! The skin tones are tanned, the images also have vibrant colours.

EDIT: How is the faded look, the desaturated feel yet the vibrant individual colours, and the skin has that tanned colour still. I'm after this look. The pictures are not bright looking, more flat.

I've tried playing with the Curve Tool and desaturating but I'm not getting there.

I'm racking my brain and have tried a ton of processes but nothing yet!!

How does she achieve this look in LR/PS?!

The images below have vibrant colours, yet have the matte/desaturated feel. The skin tones have a tanned feel. The images are not too bright. The colours are very vibrant, the red, the greens, blues, yet has that faded look.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What look? Please be more descriptive both in the question itself and in the body of the description about *exactly* what it is about these images that you wish to replicate. Otherwise all of the *how do I get this look* questions are totally indistinguishable from one another.

Comment: Your links have many photos. Could you [edit] again to one specific photo perhaps with some notes overlaid pointing out what part you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "faded look" in your examples appears to me like a **reduction in exposure** (see how the whites actually look gray in the first picture) combined with a **reduction in contrast** (achievable via an inverted S-curve), and finally an **increase in saturation** and/or **vibrance**. Also the first picture in particular looks as if **clarity** was increased to boost the face contours while maintaining the overall flat look.